# Excel VBA Search and Update

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that can search multiple results and show in rows Bxx-Dxx.

```
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim resultrow As Long

resultrow = 11

lastrow = Sheets("Klanten").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("resultcells").ClearContents
count = 0
For x = 5 To lastrow
    If Sheets("Klanten").Cells(x, 2) = Sheet1.Range("C6") Then
        Sheet1.Range("C11").Offset(count) = Sheets("Klanten").Cells(x, 1)
        Sheet1.Range("B11").Offset(count) = Sheets("Klanten").Cells(x, 2)
        Sheet1.Range("D11").Offset(count) = Sheets("Klanten").Cells(x, 11)
        count = count + 1
End If


Next x

End Sub
```

I would like to modify the result after a search has occurred and then update it.

Like in this scenario:

> A customer buys something and get loyalty points, The owner search his
>   name in excel and update his points to a *new* value.

The form look like this:

[image]

The last column contains the client his/her points from the shop.

I would like to make it so that you can edit the points directly form the search result and press the button *"Pas punten aan"* so that the points are modified or updated in the other sheet with the customers data.

The reason i am asking this is because i have zero experience with VBA itself let alone VBA in Excel.

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous answer was not really an answer to the question I see now. Have you wrote the VBA script above yourself, or did you get it from someone? The reason I ask is to determine how to explain to you what needs to be done.

Comment: I got it from a site because i have zero experience with VBA, but i am experienced in c#, java, javascript, etc...

Comment: But i know what the code does by reading it so i understand it , but i don't know any syntaxes thus this question